# how to update json file in Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a json file , I am reading json file and displaying it. when I click on an item I want to update the contents in json. currently I do not have any back end service just created a json file and reading from it. I am trying to update the values in json.

Here is my code:

In my service class:

```
loadjsonfile:function(){

var promise= $http.get('json/items.json').success(function(response){
itemList = response;
...
...
}
```

In controller class:

```
$scope.itemList = function(){
return service.loadjsonfile();
}
```

In view file:

```
<div ng-repeat="items in itemList()">
 <div ng-clcik="selectedItem(items)">
  {{item.id}} {{item.status}}
</div>
```

here , when I click on items item.status should change from new to checked . how to update the json file?

Comment: You need server code to write to file. There are lots of data services you could use instead

Comment: could you provide me example of those data services.

Comment: not hard to find in a web search

Answer (score 0):

Angular two-way binding works over browser-memory-object, it does not work on files.

If you want to update your json file, you need to rewrite .json file by yourself, to do that use [HTML5 API for Local Storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/).