# How to get the states, that dynamically generated by ui-sref

Tags: angularjs

I have ui-sref that generates states dynamically.

```
<li class="mega-menu" ng-repeat="gethead in details" ><a style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;" class="level-top" href="" ui-sref="menu.({id:menu._id})">{{gethead.ctgname}}</a></li>
```

Now my question is, I want to access or go to those states dynamically using $stateProvider.state().

```
$stateProvider.state("menu.({id:menu._id})", url:"/abc",templateUrl:"partials/abc/{{ctgname}}.html"})
```

Comment: You can't.  This seems like a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483262/how-to-update-json-file-in-angular-js)

Comment: Guys i got the answer,.. We can get and also change the states by the help of the $stateParam. We have to pass it to the api which we are calling thats it.